# Puppet copy and install program on users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

Trying to write module to install nomachine on every user how created on ubuntu deskop.
I need assist to solve two problem:

1. nbadmin its my user but I woluld like to write genral user
2. second I got message error when I tried to install on my user
   error message=
   Failed to apply catalog: Parameter mode failed on File[/home/nbadmin/nomachine_6.9.2_1_amd64.deb]: The file mode specification must be a string, not 'Integer' (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/pvm/modules/nomachine/manifests/init.pp, line: 3)

class nomachine {

```
file {
     "/home/nbadmin/nomachine_6.9.2_1_amd64.deb":
    ensure => present,
    mode => 0777,
    source => "puppet:///modules/nomachine/nomachine_6.9.2_1_amd64.deb",
    notify => Package["nomachine_6.9.2_1"],
}

package {
  "nomachine_6.9.2_1":
    provider => dpkg,
    ensure => installed,
    source => "/home/nbadmin/nomachine_6.9.2_1_amd64.deb",
    require => File["/home/nbadmin/nomachine_6.9.2_1_amd64.deb"],
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why that file is being seen by puppet as an integer, but you can create a parameter instead.

The beginning of your class will be:

```
$nomachine_deb = lookup('nomachine_deb', String)

file { $nomachine_deb:
```

in common.yaml or node.yaml

```
nomachine_deb: '/home/nbadmin/nomachine_6.9.2_1_amd64.deb'
```